# What does the following phrase mean: "pursuing invariably the same Object"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given the following sentence in the American Declaration of Independence:

> But when a long train of abuses and usurpations, **pursuing invariably
>   the same Object** evinces a design to reduce them under absolute
>   Despotism, it is their right, it is their duty, to throw off such
>   Government, and to provide new Guards for their future security.

I understand the sentence as a substantiation for the making of a new US government, however what does the particular highlighted phrase mean?

Comment: After checking the dictionary definitions of the less familiar words, such as [invariably](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/invariably) and [object](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/object) (used in this sense to mean a goal or aim), what is it you don't understand?

Comment: It might be easier if you imagine a comma after the word "object" (which in this case means "goal"). That would make it clearer that the subject of the verb "pursuing" is "the abuses and usurpations". The object (goal) of the abuses is always (invariably) the same (to keep the people from exercising their rights, mentioned far earlier). So this part of the sentence is simply describing the abuses, and then after the word object, they continue with the idea; the abuses show a plan to reduce the people to living under despotism.

Comment: I think the answer would have been easier if you noticed two things here. The use of ***the***, in fact, *the same*, before 'Object', and the **capitalization** of 'Object' itself. This suggests a reference to previous definition and/or discussion of 'Object'. What 'Object' is, is not amenable to literary speculation given the context.

Answer (score 3):

pursuing > seeking to attain

invariably > consistently

the same Object > the same goal or purpose

Answer (score 2):

It means there was a long series of events, actions, and behaviors, which all could be interpreted as *working toward the same ultimate goal*.

Answer (score 0):

The term [monomania had not yet been invented](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Monomania&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Obviously, [the concept *was* around](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomania).

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to see how this addresses the question.

Comment: The Declaration of Independence includes what later became a standard part of the definition of monomania. The implication in the declaration looks to be one of pathological behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

For God's sake, it is a fairly easy translation it is sad that people don't write like this anymore. It is one of the most important sections in the DOI. It means that when there have been a long train of abuses (by abusive government, or a controlling authority such as a king or dictator) ...then " it is their right, their duty to throw off such government and provide new guards" ....therefore if there is something wrong that those that have the ability to take action must take action and elect, overthrow or otherwise make the change like our founders did leaving England and patriots that won the revolutionary war

Comment: There's no need to be irritable. If someone doesn't understand, they don't understand. Simple as that.

Comment: Downvoted because the question specifically asks about "pursuing invariably the same Object", but this answer does not address it.
Everything in this answer I agree with, but it did not address the bold text part of the question